# Octopress, change the style sheet in a theme

Tags: sass, octopress

I'm using Octopress and I'd like to change my stylesheet. It's in a theme called 'slash'

I typed

```
rake watch
```

Then went to .themes/mytheme/sass/parts/_syntax.scss and changed some of the code.

but it looks like I get the message:

```
unchanged sass/screen.scss
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add or override styles, edit `sass/custom/_styles.scss`. This stylesheet is imported last, so you can override styles with the cascade. [More info](http://octopress.org/docs/theme/styles/)